# Prove of irreducibility of polynomial over field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+...+x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$ for $p$ prime. I have read somewhere it used the fact that $(p,p-1)=1$, but I don't understand. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Can you first argue why $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \ldots + x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? And then - secondly - why it must remain irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$?

Comment: For the first question yes, change $x$ to $x+1$ and then use Eisenstein. For the second of course not so that I asked the question.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174526/irreducible-polynomial-in-field-extension?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your reference