# Irreducible polynomial in field extension (alternative proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am interested in the following theorem.

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension of degree $n$. Let $P(X)$ be a degree $d$ polynomial that is irreducible over $K$. If $n$ and $d$ are relatively prime, then $P(X)$ is irreducible over $L.$

I found a [proof of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174526/irreducible-polynomial-in-field-extension) using tower law calculations, but I would like to ask if it can be proved in an alternative way using permutations and conjugates? I want a more explicit proof in order to better understand this theorem. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t want to definitively say it can’t be proved in such an alternate way, but I’m not sure how it could be. The tower law (and this result) has much more to do with the vector space structure of field extensions, namely via dimension. But what you’re asking about has to do with the automorphism groups, which themselves could all be trivial.

Comment: @J.G that negative answer satisfies me enough! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it! But I think this is a really nice question; wondering why a result really holds/if there’s a more illuminating way to do it is a really great exercise (that frankly I should do myself far more often).